# Is it possible to get a combox reference from a store? ExtJS 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, store

Following scenario:

```
                          {
                                xtype: 'combo',
                                displayField: 'LANGTEXT',
                                valueField: 'KURZTEXT',
                                store: {
                                    remoteSort: false,
                                    autoLoad: false,
                                    pageSize: 999999,
                                    fields: [
                                        { name: 'KURZTEXT', type: 'string' },
                                        { name: 'LANGTEXT', type: 'string' }
                                    ],
                                    proxy: {
                                        type: 'ajax',
                                        url: 'callHandler.cfc',
                                        actionMethods: { read: 'POST' },
                                        reader: {
                                            type: 'json',
                                            rootProperty: 'DATA.ROWS',
                                            totalProperty: 'TOTALCOUNT'
                                        }
                                        
                                    },
                                    listeners: {
                                        load: function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts ){
                                            //is something like this possible?
                                            var combo = store.getCombo()
                                            
                                        }
                                    }
                                }                      
                            }
```

Is it possible to get the combobox reference from the store with something like this:  `store.getCombo()`? I know that normally you can only get the store reference from the combobox. But I thought maybe it works also the other way around, if the store is created in the combobox?

Comment: As far am aware, we cannot get the component from store because a single store can be used in multiple components and all these store copies in each component will be same. So in short its not possible. Why do you want to use this `store.getCombo()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check the combobox [afterQuery](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.html#method-afterQuery) template method.

It's a configuration available for the combobox component that works almost similar to the store's load event. Here you have access to both the combobox component and the store.

I think the drawback is: it only gets called when the combo trigger is clicked or a value is typed in the combo's textfield. I believe this would already be help if you want to do your post-processing after these events.

```
{
    xtype: 'combo',
    displayField: 'LANGTEXT',
    valueField: 'KURZTEXT',
    store: {
        remoteSort: false,
        autoLoad: false,
        pageSize: 999999,
        fields: [
            { name: 'KURZTEXT', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'LANGTEXT', type: 'string' }
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'callHandler.cfc',
            actionMethods: { read: 'POST' },
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'DATA.ROWS',
                totalProperty: 'TOTALCOUNT'
            }
            
        }
    },

    afterQuery: function (queryPlan) {
        var combo = queryPlan.combo; // I guess `var combo = this;`  should work too..
        var store = combo.getStore();


        // always return queryPlan
        return queryPlan;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any issue or questions.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I could think of was to write a custom matcher function.

You could do this by overriding the Ext.Component and adding the matcher function like this:

```
    Ext.override(Ext.Component, {
        hasStoreId: function (storeId) {
            if (Ext.isFunction(this.getStore) && this.getStore().storeId) {
                return this.getStore().storeId === storeId;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now that you have a matcher function for every component you can search for all components with given storeId like this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("{hasStoreId('mystore')}");
```

You can also be more precise and only search for combos that match the criteria like this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("combo{hasStoreId('mystore')}");
```

Now that you have all combos with the given storeId you should easily be able to retrieve the combo you need.

Here a Sencha fiddle with a working example:
[example code](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3egk)